# Windows NT pc stuck on boot

Tags: windows, boot, freeze

Client PC boots, then stick at wallpaper and won't continue to load login dialog (even in safe-mode).

Any suggestions?  I'm too new school for this. Haha

Comment: Which version? 3.5? 4.0? Windows 2000? Vista? Windows 7?

Comment: @AndrewJ.Brehm, I would assume 3-4 since he’s “too new school”.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't worked with NT for too long, but some usual things-

- Does Ctrl-Alt-Del or Ctrl-Alt-Esc do anything?
- Is there a repair facility on the install disk (assuming client still has it)?
- Does NT have a chkdisk ability?
- Use a live CD (Ubuntu) to copy data and reinstall (either with NT or a newer OS)

Comment: *C-A-D doesn't do a thing.  The computer squats at the start up screen (wallpaper background).
*No install disk.
*Cannot get to CMD 
*Ubuntu is a last resort.